# Magento 2 salesrule obsersver save after & before

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-rule

In Magento 1.9 i have an observer `salesrule_rule_save_before` and `salesrule_rule_save_after` for the backend area, are there any equivalent observer like this in Magento 2
?

Answer (score 0):

This two-events are also exiting at  Magento 2. Version.

`salesrule_rule_save_before` and `salesrule_rule_save_after` are both are global event means it can fire  from Admin or Frontend OR WebApi.

But if you define your observer under **adminhtml area of etc** folder of your `app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/adminhtml`,then o*bservers write for this event will only fire for adminhtml area*.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="salesrule_rule_save_before">
        <observer name="myObserverNameOne" instance="MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="salesrule_rule_save_after">
        <observer name="myObserverNametwo" instance="MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\AnotherObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```